# android - java game, array list items flicker when removed in method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im working on making a basic game at the moment, and Im a bit confused, Ive added random blocks appearing above the screen everything works 99%, Everything falls nicely to be honest it works perfectly, but one thing is a bit annoying.

When the blocks get removed weather that's from hitting the bottom of the screen or when player hits it the other blocks flicker. Almost like the bitmap is being redrawn, but Im not redrawing?

Below is the code corresponding to drawing the blocks.

Bitmap calling:

```
private List<Collectone> block = new ArrayList<>();

private Bitmap collectonebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.block);
private Bitmap collectonebitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.block2);
private Bitmap collectonebitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.block3);
```

Adding the blocks to the arrays

```
switch (random) {
  case 1:
    enemies.add(new Enemy(this, enemybitmap, randomposX, topofscreen));
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap, randomposXtwo, topofscreen-400));
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap3, randomposXthree, topofscreen-800));
    break;
  case 2:
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap2, randomposX, topofscreen-400));
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap, randomposXtwo, topofscreen-800));
    enemies.add(new Enemy(this, enemybitmap, randomposXtwo, topofscreen));
    break;
  case 3:
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap3, randomposX, topofscreen));
    block.add(new Collectone(this, collectonebitmap2, randomposXtwo, topofscreen-400));
    break;
}
```

The loop for drawing blocks

```
for(int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
  block.get(i).draw(canvas);
  Rect playerone = player.getBounds();
  Rect Collect1 = block.get(i).getBounds();
  if (block.get(i).returnY() > bottomofscreen){ //TODO change to bottom of screen
    block.remove(i);
    break;
  }
  if (block.get(i).checkCollision(playerone, Collect1)){
    block.remove(i);
    Score += 1;
    break;
  }
}
```

Basically I Want to stop the images from Flickering when one item gets removed?

Comment: When you remove a block you are breaking your draw loop. Is that intentional? Because you basically draw 0 -> removedBlock and the other blocks don't get drawn so they will not be on screen for one frame == flickering.

Comment: @Ben ahh okay! so how could i not break my draw loop and still remove the block that hits the bottom of screen or player?

Comment: @Ben, ive just realised what you mean ... wow, yes ive removed the breaks on the for loop but if i remove the breaks from the random draw its doubles everything, but neither fix the flickering